Traveling to Schengen Area countries which are admited only for air and maritime borders
Context: I have been in Schengen for 90 days on the dot, therefore when trying to enter Schengen area, they will check my passport and count the days to see if I am allowed to enter.
What I want to do is travel from Macedonia through Serbia and into Romania via car. Romania is in Schengen only for air and maritime vessels. Will they check my passport to see if I've stayed for over 90 days in Schengen?
The trip is short and recreational in nature with the goal of attending festive events during the holiday season.

"I have been in Schengen for 90 days on the dot": depending on when the actual days of presence were, there might be no problem.  When did you most recently leave the Schengen area?  How long were you in the Schengen area on that visit?  Have you put your travel dates in the Schengen calculator?  If, for example, you made 9 trips of 10 days each on the first and 16th of each month from June to September and one from the first to the tenth of October, then you can enter for up to 10 days on the 30th of November or up to 30 days on the 10th of December.

@phoog it was a continuous stay in Germany for 89 days in Germany and 1 day in Greece, the last travel to Greece happened in October and I returned from Germany in early October. I am pretty sure that Schengen rules are out of 180 days, 90 days have to be spent out of schengen, is that not correct?

"I am pretty sure that Schengen rules are out of 180 days, 90 days have to be spent out of schengen, is that not correct?" It is correct, but the application of the rule to a series of stays of shorter duration is a bit counterintuitive, as the example in my previous comment should show.  After a single 90-day stay, however, the consequence is fairly intuitive: you can't reenter for the next 90 days; on the 91st day after you leave, you can re-enter for up to 90 days.  If you were in the Schengen area for 90 consecutive days ending in early October then you cannot reenter until early January.

I think you misunderstand the status of Romania. Romania is in Schengen, but: on air and ferry you get no control for travels "intra-Schengen" (between Schengen territories), but you get normal passport checks on the other borders.
In your case: when you enter Romania from Serbia, you get the usual Schengen controls, and it doesn't matter if you fly or you go with a car.
And in any case, it is up to you to verify the 90 days. Not having a check will not reset the days. (Schengen borders are sometime weird, weirder than such case)

So in the case of Romania, I am still subject to the 90 days rule since I am not a citizen of the EU. And as for the checks, they always check non-eu citizens to see if they have stayed 90 days or more in Schengen, at least they do for Balkan countries since there might be a bit more incidents here :/

I do not know how they check (and I do not think they check systematically about the 90 days, also they do not check the 90 days inside Schengen: it is your task not to pass the limits (and it is not about the border). [Swiss here: we didn't have many checks also when we were outside Schengen. Now Schengen seems more consistent on controls). -- If you European, you may get other ways, but it depends on your country, and reasons (and maybe expatriates may be more relevant on that).

Oh I thought you were Italian because of the last name :) Anyway, in my experience, whenever I cross border to get into EU, they always get my passport and count all the stamps. I mostly cross via Greece, Bulgaria, Hungary, Croatia, or via airplane. Whenever I am on an airplane landing in an EU country (i.e. Poland, Austria, Germany, Italy etc), it goes smooth. On the land border, they always count my days manually. Maybe they don't have the software to count the days for them ? I don't know.

Giacomo is right, Romania has no checks by air or sea but does by land border. That doesn't mean you aren't subject to the 90 day rule. Unrelated: The reason they count the days manually is because there is no central database recording entries and exits (yet).

@Dimitar It's a matter of risk assessment and plain old prejudice. The rule is the same for everybody, checks are more thorough for visa holders, people traveling with cheaper means of transportation (e.g. bus) or even based on physical appearance. I travelled by bus through the region with a US passport holder and the checks were always very superficial for us (e.g. she had stayed more than 90 days in the Schengen area but I don't think the Greek border guards asked to see her residence permit), not so much for North Macedonia citizens in the same bus.

@GiacomoCatenazzi about how they check: on the border, the stamps are entered into a calculator like this (if not exactly that one), which calculates how long the traveler can enter for, and if the traveler is out of days, when they can next enter and for how long. Once EES rolls out it'll be a bit more streamlined.

@ave: yeah, but if you enter by car, you do not have a return ticket, so not much to check. And if the passport was not flagged on exit (overstaying), probably you are allowed to enter for at least one day, so it makes the check almost useless (but random check, and risk amassment). My point is that probably any overstaying is "perpetuated" later (and so not much a think of border control). Land borders have a much different dynamic.
